# How to correctly define a variable to correct object scope

Tags: javascript

```
myvar = whatever;

namespace.myspace.Create = function () {
    this.myvar = null;
    this.MyFunction = function (val) {
        this.myvar = val;
    }
}

---

namespace.myspace.Create = function () {
    var myvar = null;
    this.MyFunction = function (val) {
        this.myvar = val;
    }
}

---

namespace.myspace.Create = function () {
    myvar = null;
    this.MyFunction = function (val) {
        this.myvar = val;
    }
}

var myObject = new namespace.myspace.Create();
```

Looking at the above code, especially the  myvar being defined as:

- this.myvar = null;
- var myvar = null;
- myvar = null;

What are the main differences, scopes and uses of these? Any pitfalls or preferred ways of doing?  Any of these just flat out wrong and should not be used?

Comment: `myvar = whatever` global. `this.myvar = null` context or instance. `var myvar = null` local. `myvar = null` global.

Comment: Which one you'd use depends on what you're trying to achieve. Note that all three of your examples set an instance variable with `this.myvar` inside `this.MyFunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myvar` is a global variable

`this.myvar` is a public variable scoped on the `myspace` namespace

and `var myvar` is a private variable that is also scoped on the `myspace` namespace